# gaps between charts in Report Builder due to table beneath

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

This seems more of a SuperUser thing but I didn't see any Report Builder or SSRS tags there.  Move if it's in the wrong place, please!

When I create a report in Report Builder 2, I often have charts on top and then a table underneath.  The problem I encounter is that some charts get shoved over to the right, seemingly due to the table width.  I'll have a few charts snuggly against each other, as I designed them, then the rest in the same row will get pushed over to align with the right side of the table beneath them, leaving a big gap between the charts on the left and the charts on the right.

How can I "disconnect" the table from the charts such that the charts don't care where the table ends, and they just stay pressed against each other with no gaps between them?

It's like this:

```
[chart][chart]          [chart][chart]
[table-----------------]
```

And I want this:

```
[chart][chart][chart][chart]
[table-----------------]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered kind of a "cheap" way of fixing this.  Just add an extra column to the table and stretch it such that it takes up the remaining width of the charts above.  Make the column's background and border colors white or transparent so that it isn't visible.

```
[chart][chart][chart][chart]
[table----hidden column----]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out another way of doing this? I'm having a related issue where I have multiple tables in the same horizontal space, but they don't use the same spacing that I used in the designer.